# Sudoku elimination strategy

Tags: python, algorithm, sudoku

Suppose I have Sudoku array which is used in Sudoku solver such as:

```py
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0]
 [2 0 7 0 0 9 0 0 0]
 [6 0 0 3 5 1 0 0 0]
 [5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 8]
 [0 0 0 8 2 0 5 3 0]
 [0 0 0 0 7 0 8 0 4]
 [0 0 6 2 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 8 0 0 0 0 7 0 0]]
```

And I have a method `nextMove()` which for now returns next coordinates the solver has to check
the current implementation is:

```py
for x in range(9):
    for y in range(9):
        if sudoku[x][y] == 0:
            return [x,y]
```

While reading norwigs book on algos I've stumbled upon eliminatiion strategy which I would like to try applying in the solver. My basic idea was to check which row+column combination has the least possibilities (the most numbers around)

I've tried:

```py
def next_move(sudoku):
    row = 0
    current_number_row = 0
    current_number_column = 0
    column = 0
    max_num_col = 0
    max_num_row = 0

    for x in range(9):
        current_number_row = 0
        for y in range(9):
            if sudoku[x][y] != 0:
                current_number_row += 1
        if current_number_row > max_num_row and current_number_row < 9:
            max_num_row = current_number_row
            row = x
    for m in range(9):
        current_number_column = 0
        if sudoku[row][m] == 0:
            for g in range(9):
                if sudoku[g][m] != 0:
                    current_number_column += 1
        if current_number_column > max_num_col and current_number_column < 9:
            max_num_col = current_number_column
            column = m
    return [row, column]
```

However that doesn't work since sometimes the algorithm keeps returning the same position although it was already filled.

How can I write the elimination strategy to improve performance while still be able to solve the Sudoku?

Comment: In the if block you assigned "column = m", you should also check sudoku[row][m] == 0. Because "row" being the row with the most numbers does not mean every cell in that row is empty.

Comment: Isn't that what I do in the M loop?

Comment: Yeah that is mistake by me, maybe if you inspect a state where your function returns an invalid cell it would be easier to find the bug.

Comment: That's qute hard to find in 3.4milion calls on that function :(

Comment: Can't you just detect when returned [row, column] is a non-empty cell?

Answer (score 4):

To make this elimination strategy efficient, you would need to have a data structure that keeps track of the neighbours as you make your moves.  Re-computing them for every position every time is going to slow things down rather than improve performance.

Such a structure could be a set of non-conflicting numbers that remain available at each position after making a move or it could be the conflicting numbers to be excluded instead.  You also need to make updating this structure as efficient as possible when you make a move or take it back.  This can be done by creating a second structure that maps each position to the positions that need to be updated when a number is placed there.

In addition to that, since each position can conflict in 3 dimensions (vertical, horizontal and blocks), you need 3 distinct groups to handle addition/subtraction of neighbours in the sets.  So each number placed at a given position has to invalidate other positions on a group basis.

Here is a small version of sudoku solver that uses this exclusion approach:

```
def shortSudokuSolve(board):  # expects a list of lists as the board
    size    = len(board)
    block   = int(size**0.5)
    board   = [n for row in board for n in row ]      
    span    = { (n,p): { (g,n)  for g in (n>0)*[p//size, size+p%size,
                                 2*size+p%size//block+p//size//block*block] }
                for p in range(size*size) for n in range(size+1) }
    empties = [i for i,n in enumerate(board) if n==0 ]
    used    = set().union(*(span[n,p] for p,n in enumerate(board) if n))
    empty   = 0
    while empty>=0 and empty<len(empties):       
        pos        = empties[empty]
        used      -= span[board[pos],pos]
        board[pos] = next((n for n in range(board[pos]+1,size+1) 
                          if not span[n,pos]&used),0)
        used      |= span[board[pos],pos]
        empty     += 1 if board[pos] else -1            
    return [board[r:r+size] for r in range(0,size*size,size)]
```

Output:

```
test =  [ [8,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0],
          [0,0,3, 6,0,0, 0,0,0],
          [0,7,0, 0,9,0, 2,0,0],

          [0,5,0, 0,0,7, 0,0,0],
          [0,0,0, 0,4,5, 6,0,0],
          [0,0,0, 1,0,0, 0,3,0],

          [0,0,1, 0,0,0, 0,6,8],
          [0,0,8, 5,0,0, 0,1,0],
          [0,9,0, 0,0,0, 4,0,0]
        ]
solution = shortSudokuSolve(test)
printSudoku(test,solution)

╔═══╤═══╤═══╦═══╤═══╤═══╦═══╤═══╤═══╗ ╔═══╤═══╤═══╦═══╤═══╤═══╦═══╤═══╤═══╗
║ 8 │   │   ║   │   │   ║   │   │   ║ ║ 8 │ 1 │ 2 ║ 7 │ 5 │ 4 ║ 3 │ 9 │ 6 ║
╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢ ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
║   │   │ 3 ║ 6 │   │   ║   │   │   ║ ║ 9 │ 4 │ 3 ║ 6 │ 8 │ 2 ║ 1 │ 5 │ 7 ║
╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢ ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
║   │ 7 │   ║   │ 9 │   ║ 2 │   │   ║ ║ 6 │ 7 │ 5 ║ 3 │ 9 │ 1 ║ 2 │ 8 │ 4 ║
╠═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╣ ╠═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╣
║   │ 5 │   ║   │   │ 7 ║   │   │   ║ ║ 1 │ 5 │ 6 ║ 9 │ 3 │ 7 ║ 8 │ 4 │ 2 ║
╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢ ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
║   │   │   ║   │ 4 │ 5 ║ 6 │   │   ║ ║ 3 │ 8 │ 9 ║ 2 │ 4 │ 5 ║ 6 │ 7 │ 1 ║
╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢ ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
║   │   │   ║ 1 │   │   ║   │ 3 │   ║ ║ 7 │ 2 │ 4 ║ 1 │ 6 │ 8 ║ 9 │ 3 │ 5 ║
╠═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╣ ╠═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╣
║   │   │ 1 ║   │   │   ║   │ 6 │ 8 ║ ║ 2 │ 3 │ 1 ║ 4 │ 7 │ 9 ║ 5 │ 6 │ 8 ║
╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢ ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
║   │   │ 8 ║ 5 │   │   ║   │ 1 │   ║ ║ 4 │ 6 │ 8 ║ 5 │ 2 │ 3 ║ 7 │ 1 │ 9 ║
╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢ ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
║   │ 9 │   ║   │   │   ║ 4 │   │   ║ ║ 5 │ 9 │ 7 ║ 8 │ 1 │ 6 ║ 4 │ 2 │ 3 ║
╚═══╧═══╧═══╩═══╧═══╧═══╩═══╧═══╧═══╝ ╚═══╧═══╧═══╩═══╧═══╧═══╩═══╧═══╧═══╝
```

*Note that this is merely an illustration of the mechanics, while it will quickly solve 9x9 sudoku puzzles, more subtle exclusion/prioritization of number selections would be needed to handle 16x16 or larger sudokus in a reasonable amount of time.*

*I do have an optimized version of the solver (too large to share here) that determines empty cell priorities, detects dead ends early (any position with all numbers excluded, groups with fewer options than empty cells), and auto-places single number options.  That one can solve 16x16 puzzles in under a second and can handle some 36x36 in about a minute.*

Here is the `printsudoku` function i used for the output:

```
def niceSudo(board):
    side    = len(board)
    base    = int(side**0.5)
    def expandLine(line):
        return line[0]+line[5:9].join([line[1:5]*(base-1)]*base)+line[9:13]
    line0  = expandLine("╔═══╤═══╦═══╗")
    line1  = expandLine("║ . │ . ║ . ║")
    line2  = expandLine("╟───┼───╫───╢")
    line3  = expandLine("╠═══╪═══╬═══╣")
    line4  = expandLine("╚═══╧═══╩═══╝")

    symbol = " 123456789" if base <= 3 else " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    nums   = [ [""]+[symbol[n] for n in row] for row in board ]
    lines  = []
    lines.append(line0)
    for r in range(1,side+1):
        lines.append( "".join(n+s for n,s in zip(nums[r-1],line1.split("."))) )
        lines.append([line2,line3,line4][(r%side==0)+(r%base==0)])
    return lines
        
def printSudoku(*boards):
    print(*(" ".join(ss) for ss in zip(*(niceSudo(b) for b in boards))),sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

To start, lets try rewriting your existing approach, a bit simpler-

```py
def find_best(grid):
    row_counts = [row.count(0) for row in grid]
    col_counts = [col.count(0) for col in zip(*grid)]

    cells_with_scores = ((row_count + col_count, row_idx, col_idx) 
            for row_count, (row_idx, row)  in zip(row_counts, enumerate(grid))
            for col_count, (col_idx, elem) in zip(col_counts, enumerate(row)) 
            if elem)

    score, row_num, col_num = min(cells_with_scores)
    return row_num, col_num
```

Note that we're just calculating the count of 0's on each row/col, iterating over every cell, and discarding any that are non-zero. We then get the min tuple, which will be one with the smallest `row_count + col_count`.

Now, this is of course `O(N*M)`, where `N` is the number of rows, and `M` the number of columns. This isn't great, but it is simple, and we can improve on it.

To do so, we need to construct a priority queue / min-heap from the priority/coordinate tuples in `cells_with_scores` (and switch to lists instead of tuples, for reasons we'll see shortly). We can use the builtin `heapq` module to do this. Then, we can get the min in `O(1)` time, after initial construction. However, we'll need to update this queue with the new cell scores after making a move, which means for every cell in the same row or column as the assigned cell, we need to decrement the priority key for that corresponding element in the heap by 1.

You can roll your own to do this, or can make a mapping of row_num -> list of `cells_with_scores` entries, and same for col_num. Then, iterate this list (skip any non-zero cells), and mutate the corresponding count/row/col list to decrease the count (in place), and restore the heap invariant. You can create a function to use this, or if you're willing to use a private / undocumented (and prone to change) method from `heapq`, use `heapq._siftdown`.  Either way, once all the keys are decremented and the heap invariant restored, you're ready to get the next min.

All together, this approach will take `O((M + N) * log(N * M)` time.

Comment: Hi I've tried the method you provided, however it looks like the code doesn't compile ` if elem))
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @gaming4mining ah, my last change (adding the 'if elem') put the parenthesis in the wrong spot

Comment: the algorithm is more important than the actual implementation- I provide the code as a reference for the following paragraph, where I explain an asymptotically (much) faster algorithm